Convert list to vector in coq
I'm pretty new to using coq and I'm a bit confused about vectors. I want to convert a list into a vector with the same content. I'm trying pattern matching, but it keeps throwing errors about the empty vector. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Fixpoint list_to_vec {X : Type} (l : list X) : Vector.t X (length l) :=
  match l with
  | List.nil => nil
  | List.cons h t => cons X h (length t) (list_to_vec t)
  end.


You are missing the argument to nil that tells it which type the Vector should have:
Fixpoint list_to_vec {X : Type} (l : list X) : Vector.t X (length l) :=
  match l with
  | List.nil => nil X
  | List.cons h t => cons X h (length t) (list_to_vec t)
  end.

that works.
I'm not sure why this argument is not implicit by default, like with List.nil.

I missed that this is defined above:
Require Import Vector.
Arguments nil {A}.
Arguments cons {A} h {n} v.
When I'm trying your solution it throws the following error:
Illegal application (Non-functional construction):
The expression "nil" of type "t ?A 0" cannot be applied to the term
"X" : "Type"

Now it's working with:
Fixpoint list_to_vec {X : Type} (l : list X) : Vector.t X (length l) :=
  match l with
  | List.nil => nil
  | List.cons h t => cons h (list_to_vec t)
  end.

and:
Arguments nil {A}.
Arguments cons {A} h {n} v.

I'm little bit confused about this but it's working.
